# NSMutableURLRequest POST method with multiple objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutableurlrequest

Below is my POST request example which saves Employee details. This work fine and I'm sending individual employee details.

But what if I have to save more then one Employee details...do I have to call below method those many time's ... How can I send all data in individual object like nsmutablearray of nsmutable dictionary....

```
-(void)saveEmployDetails
{
  NSString * strBody = @"Employee=1&Class=tes&Comp=test&Type=Fixed";

        NSString *strUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/api/external/SaveEmployee?type=%@", strCompURL, strType];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl]];
        request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
        request.HTTPBody = [strBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        request.timeoutInterval = 5;
        NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [sessionMnger dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
          {
              [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
              if (!error) {
                  NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
                  if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200)
                  {
                      NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization   JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
                      NSLog(@"data:%@", jsonData);
                  }
              }
              else
                  NSLog(@"Error:%@", error.description);

          }];
        [task resume];
}
```

Webservice Team gave me body for above API POST call like

```
This is a Post Method and below is the Body Object
    [
      {
     "Employee":937,
     "Class":test,
     "Comp":test,
     "Type":test
       }
    ]
```

How to send more then one employee details together in above API

Comment: Why don't you send the data as json to your service? If your service accept json, you can send NSMutableArray of NSDictionary for example.

Comment: you mean to say instead of string .... i had same thing in mind.... will try ...but was not sure if it allows...

Comment: I always prefer sending data as json array or object to the server. In which language is your webservice developed?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

So the Webservice accepts json. 
Just create an NSDictionary like this:

```
NSDictionary *emp = @{@"Employee":[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                      @"Class":@"Test",
                      @"Comp":@"Test",
                      @"Type":@"test"};

NSDictionary *emp1 = @{@"Employee":[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                      @"Class":@"Test2",
                      @"Comp":@"Test2",
                       @"Type":@"test2"};


NSArray *uploadArray = @[emp,emp1];

NSString *strUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/api/external/SaveEmployee?type=%@", strCompURL, strType];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl]];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
[request setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:uploadArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil]];
request.timeoutInterval = 5;
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [sessionMnger dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                              {
                                  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
                                  if (!error) {
                                      NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
                                      if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200)
                                      {
                                          NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization   JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
                                          NSLog(@"data:%@", jsonData);
                                      }
                                  }
                                  else
                                      NSLog(@"Error:%@", error.description);

                              }];
[task resume];
```

Comment: Accoiding to above question: He has to set data like Employee=1&Class=tes&Comp=test&Type=Fixed with dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding Encoding.

Comment: hello i tried with array of dictionary like above but API do not accept dictionary as per webservice team. they asked me to send like LIST. Objective C do not have LIST , how i can send above data instead of dictionary...

Comment: In Objective C the list is NSMutableArray. But we already wrapped it dictionary in an array `NSArray *uploadArray = @[emp,emp1];` is the short way of writing `NSArray *uploadArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:emp1,emp2nil];`

Comment: yes i am too sending data same way...but table did not got updated.... i contacted web service team they are saying they are expecting object in form of LIST, is there any other way ...do i have to convert NSArray to string then to JSOn something....

Comment: No, the format is correct, jou can validate the result with this code `NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:_uploadArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
        
        NSString *tmp = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:postData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",tmp);`

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can POST n number of employee details using your Web Service.

Comment: hmm i am not from web service team ...we have all different team working .... will take some time asking feedback...but if it does allow ....i just have to send nsmutable array of dictionary  in place of string right?

Comment: As you have updated the answer and i can see you can POST n number of employe data

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want to pass the `NSArray` inside the `NSDictionary` as a parameter along with the url to server.
Try like Hermann Klecker's answer and make changes accordingly:

```
  [
  {
      "Employee":1,
      "Class":"test 1",
      "Comp":"test 1",
      "Type":"test 1"
   },
  {
      "Employee":2,
      "Class":"test 2",
      "Comp":"test 2",
      "Type":"test 2"
   }
]
```

Convert array into `json` string or make dictionary of post data than convert it into `json` string and post string to server.

Comment: NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]   initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Employee", @"Class",@"Comp",@"Type", nil];
Where is object?? They all are key

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you will have to form a body like this:

```
[
  {
      "Employee":1,
      "Class":"test 1",
      "Comp":"test 1",
      "Type":"test 1"
   },
  {
      "Employee":2,
      "Class":"test 2",
      "Comp":"test 2",
      "Type":"test 2"
   }
]
```

Comment: how to form above body.....array of dictionary won't work as per web service team...LIST is not available in Objective C

Comment: Why don't you use an NSArray then or NSMutableArray? That is the closest counterpart in Obj-C to List in Java.

Comment: I guess the shortest option is as follows: `@[@{@"Employee":@1,@"Class":@"test 1",@"Comp":@"test 1",@"Type":@"test 1"},@{@"Employee":@2,@"Class":@"test 2",@"Comp":@"test 2",@"Type":@"test 2"}] `

Answer (score -1):

replace you string body

`NSString * strBody = @"Employee = 1 & Class = tes & Comp = test & Type = Fixed"`

to

```
NSString * strBody = @"Employee=1&Class=tes&Comp=test&Type=Fixed"
```

Comment: yes i have same ..it was an example... my question is different ..... what if i have to send data of more then one employee.... how object should go...?