# sending List of Objects as LIST to POST API

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using POST API to send a list of objects like below:

```
{
 "EmpID":1,
 "EmpDetailID":2,
 "WorkID":3,
 "TestDetailID":4,
 "QuantityRequired":5
 }
```

I am sending an array of dictionaries, but the web service team has informed me that the dictionary would not work. I have to send it as LIST, but there is no list in Objective C

I tried the following methods:

```
NSDictionary *dicTest = @{@"EmpID":1,
                      @"EmpDetailID":2,
                      @"WorkID":3,
                      @"TestDetailID":4,
                      @"QuantityRequired":5
                      };
[arrTest addObject: dicTest];
```

I also tried array of arrays with single objects / multiple objects.
But nothing is working. POST call is fine only I wanted to send data in LIST form.

How do I need to send the above data in LIST form?

Comment: Can you try to improve the question with information about the technologies you're talking about, backend handling and sample of your list? The sample you provided is an object, not a list or array.

Comment: in LIST means? can show how?

Comment: Eg: 
{
 "EmpID":1,
 "EmpDetailID":2,
 "WorkID":3,
 "TestDetailID":4,
 "QuantityRequired":5
 }

Comment: Second post to the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41481525/nsmutableurlrequest-post-method-with-multiple-objects/41482337?noredirect=1#comment70471033_41482337

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray  *array1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"\"EmpID\":1", @"\"EmpDetailID\":2", @"\"WorkID\":3", nil];

NSString *joinedString = [array1 componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```